# Microsoft Bing Maps: Billable or non-Billable

Tags: bing-maps

I am using Microsoft Bing Maps for my mobile app project. The API which I am using is REST-Imagery Metadata. It shows on my account that it is billable after 25 hits. 490 hits have already occured. If the API is billable, how the billing is happening and what is the criteria for payment? Someone please clarify in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's buried in the Terms of Service - but you still get a certain number of "billable" transactions for free provided you're making a mobile-app, even a commercial app, if it's available for a non-Microsoft mobile device platform (i.e. Android and iOS). I imagine because it's free advertising for Bing Maps when users would otherwise be using rivals Google Maps or Apple Maps respectively.

Source: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/product

> (c) Limited website and mobile app use.
>
> If you are using the Services in an Application for commercial, non-commercial (except for Education or Non-profit use) or government use under these TOU, without entering into Standard Terms, then your Application must be available on a website or a mobile app running in a non-Microsoft Windows operating system, and must not exceed (i) 125,000 cumulative Billable Transactions (which will be free of charge) as defined in the Documentation, per calendar year or (ii) 5 queries per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries. If your use will exceed these limits, please contact us to license additional transactions

It looks like Microsoft will deactivate your account or block further requests once you hit that limit of 125,000 transactions/year and then you'll have to register for paid access and provide payment method details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  a basic Bing maps dev account than you will get 125k free transactions per year. Those billable transaction in usage report will be billed from your free limits. You don't have to pay anything until you exhaust the free limits. I found the below text from the Bing maps documentation.

> "Only billable transactions count towards the **free-use limits** for Basic keys, and Enterprise keys are only charged for billable transactions. Non-billable transactions do not incur charges and do not count towards **free-use limits**. To determine if your application will qualify for free use and for info about licensing and transaction limits, please see the Bing Maps licensing page and review the Bing Maps Terms of Use."
> -Bing maps dev center